# Either seat or room

Tags: usage

Which of the two is better to say

> There is **no more room** for you in this compartment.

> There is **no more seat** for you in this compartment

Actually this is a question in my exercise where I have to select only one of the above two options, but to me both seem correct.

Comment: They are both grammatical. You would choose the first if you want to pick the more *common* sentence, but not because you are rejecting one that's actually wrong. (The second is very unusual, and wouldn't normally be said. But that doesn't make it actually incorrect. As one of the answers here shows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first is correct. Used this way, 'room' is a non-count noun, meaning 'available space', so you can say 'no more room for you'. 'Seat' is a count noun so you would have to say 'no more seats'.

Answer (score 1):

"There is no more room for you" is correct. "There is no room for you" is correct. "There is no seat for you" is correct. "There are no more seats for you" is correct. "There are no seats for you" is correct. "There is no more seat for you" is usually incorrect, unless a single seat will be occupied by many people, eg a long bench seat, and it is already full.

Comment: Your final sentence is perfect. +1 You're quite correct that the second sentence is grammatical in a certain context (albeit one that's unusual.) Also correct is *there is no more **seating** for you*.